# Andengine GLES2 sprite is clipped on bottom and right

Tags: android, andengine

Trying to use andengine to load a sprite entity, but the bottom and right sides of the sprite are being cut off.

[image]

The code:

```
/*
 * Create the bitmap texture atlas for the sprite's texture region
 */
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(
        mEngine.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

/*
 * Create the sprite's texture region via the
 * BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
 */
mSpriteTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromResource(
        mBitmapTextureAtlas, c, getSpriteId());

/* Build the bitmap texture atlas */
try
{
    mBitmapTextureAtlas
            .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                    0, 1, 1));
}
catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

/*
 * Load the bitmap texture atlas into the device's gpu memory
 */
mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();

mSprite = new Sprite(getInitialX(), getInitialY(), mSpriteTextureRegion,
engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

/* Attach the marble to the Scene */

scene.attachChild(mSprite);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use createFromAsset instead of createFromResource whenever possible, since Android resamples resources, making them of variable size and compression quality. 
It appears that the problem you have may be related to that.

Try moving your image.png to the assets folder and then use this instead.

```
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texture, context, "path_to/your_file.png");
```

Comment: Awesome that fixed it. I guess this means I have to manage DPI / sprite scaling manually now right?

Comment: Glad that worked! And to answer you question about managing DPI/ sprite scaling. The answer is yes, sort of. With the different ResolutionPolicy types you have a set of tools. There's plenty written on the topic of you google it. How much work you want to put into it will depend on your project.

Answer (score -1):

```
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(
        mEngine.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);



/* Build the bitmap texture atlas */
try
{
    mBitmapTextureAtlas
            .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                    0, 1, 1));
}
catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


/*
 * Create the sprite's texture region via the
 * BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
 */
mSpriteTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromResource(
        mBitmapTextureAtlas, c, getSpriteId(), 0, 0);
/*
 * Load the bitmap texture atlas into the device's gpu memory
 */
mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();


Try this
```

Comment: Rama: I think he has to call "build" after adding the texture regions when using a BuildableBitmapTexture. Otherwise the texture regions will not be part of that built texture. BuildableBitmapTexture functions like using a spritesheet, but tis assembled by andengine at runtime.